# Query on push notification plaforms

Tags: apple-push-notifications, android-notifications

How does push notification platforms check if the app credentials(Android - app key, project id // ios - certificate etc) provided by user are genuine or not. Do they validate this at the time of app registration or while pushing a notification on to GCM - Google cloud , APN - Apple push

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics for GCM but I assume it's similar to Apple: every time you try to send a push notification, you need to connect to Apple's servers with the Push Certificate that you will have generated between them and you. The validity of the certificate is checked for every single call that you make to their servers.

Comment: Thanks nick for the information, so the certificate is getting validated only when we push the the notification to apple's server. As on date validating the certificate while registering the app is not posible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "date validating" but in all cases, the certificate is validated when you make a request to Apple to deliver one or more notifications. Only at that point will Apple check the certificate. If, for whatever reason, your certificate is not valid, an error code is returned either directly or via the APNS Feedback API. In most cases, you can regenerate the Push certificate without resubmitting a new build of your app to fix any issues you may have.